# How to search MySQL table for duplicates

Tags: mysql, search, query, sql

In MySQL, I have a table named "city" with "city_name" and "latitude" and "longitude" in it. It appears that I have a few duplicates. What query can I run (in **phpmyadmin**) that will search through the "city" table for entries containing the same latitude and longitude (with different "city_name"'s)?

Answer (score 1):

Run the query in mysql directly.  First access mysql from command line:

```
sudo mysql -p
```

Then select the database you want to use

```
show databases;
use databaseiwant;
```

Now run a query on the table you need to find duplicates in

```
show tables;
SELECT fieldtocheckduplicates, COUNT(fieldtocheckduplicates) AS NumOccurrences FROM tabletocheck GROUP BY fieldtocheckduplicates HAVING ( COUNT(fieldtocheckduplicates) > 1 );
```

Comment: As long as you're not expecting more than a few dozen duplicates, this should work fine.  You could write a similar query to delete the duplicates as well.